# Default ms-class for SVG element

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I use this code to create a hexagonal shape in JSON for a SharePoint list.

```
{
            "elmType": "svg",
            "style": {
              "fill": "currentColor",
              "cursor": "pointer"
            },
            "attributes": {
              "viewBox": "-150 -150 300 300",
              "class": "ms-fontColor-themeLight ms-bgColor-themeTertiary--hover"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "path",
                "attributes": {
                  "d": "M130,60.561C130,69.495 125.232,77.751 117.493,82.216C92.646,96.55 37.328,128.464 12.493,142.792C4.762,147.253 -4.762,147.253 -12.493,142.792C-37.328,128.464 -92.646,96.55 -117.493,82.216C-125.232,77.751 -130,69.495 -130,60.561L-130,-60.561C-130,-69.495 -125.232,-77.751 -117.493,-82.216C-92.646,-96.55 -37.328,-128.464 -12.493,-142.792C-4.762,-147.253 4.762,-147.253 12.493,-142.792C37.328,-128.464 92.646,-96.55 117.493,-82.216C125.232,-77.751 130,-69.495 130,-60.561L130,60.561Z"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

The tag "fill" applies a standard-color to the shape.
Can I use the class-definition inside the elmType-attributes to assign a different color (e.g. *ms-bgColor-themeSecondary*) instead of using hex-color-codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the use of `"fill": "currentColor"` will mean that the fill value will be inherited from the text color (`color`) and you could set that value using a class. If you want the color to be `themeTertiary` then use the class `ms-fontColor-themeTertiary`. You can also set the `fill` for individual paths using the same technique.

There are several samples using this technique in the [List Formatting Sample repo](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/search?q=%22currentColor%22). Here's an example from the relevant portion of the [Horse Crest](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/blob/8e9f7327ed98159744b3110a4cd1b3bf26a88b06/view-samples/horse-crests/horse-crests.json) sample:

```
{
  "elmType": "svg",
  "style": {
    "position": "absolute",
    "width": "88px",
    "height": "100px",
    "top": "40px",
    "left": "60px",
    "fill": "currentColor"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "path",
      "attributes": {
        "d": "M 13.293424,79.005018 C -0.23486286,59.040168 9.3124783,43.447536 9.3124783,43.447536 7.0942758,42.790838 0,47.4402 0,47.4402 3.9901158,32.817586 25.936774,20.394322 25.936774,20.394322 23.500522,19.502762 16.627352,21.273658 16.627352,21.273658 34.582366,3.9931728 56.531572,10.419033 56.531572,10.419033 57.193873,6.6474772 68.061743,0 68.061743,0 66.950094,1.10095 66.501767,7.0947858 66.501767,7.0947858 67.610358,5.09667 71.163356,3.1021214 71.163356,3.1021214 c -1.99353,4.6493614 0,14.6231246 0,14.6231246 5.763048,5.768142 12.189927,25.7228 12.189927,25.7228 l 2.445425,3.545864 c 3.104667,4.439972 1.963467,11.420638 -1.11165,13.076392 -11.52406,6.22157 -12.638765,-5.09514 -12.638765,-5.09514 C 62.514708,53.866568 55.419922,43.221844 55.419922,43.221844 42.566164,49.870848 49.725142,68.628272 55.275234,75.831063 62.406192,85.064067 57.184703,100 57.184703,100 c 0,0 -30.533151,-1.264483 -43.891279,-20.994982 z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The above use of `class` on the `svg` element with a `fill` of `currentColor` has the effect of setting the fill of the path element to the primary theme color for the site.

Comment: That's it, thank you!
Is there a way to change the stroke color like this too or do I have to enter a HEX-value for it?